# Having payment fail issues with CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob

Seem to be having issues with CartThrob and Discount codes that is leaving me with the error

```
Your payment failed: Failed: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. 10413
```

I see the error has cropped up before, but doesn't seem to have been fixed from what i can gather. Its only when using a discount code that the error is cropping up. Everything is fine on the basket but when its sent to PayPal Express then its not matching up or been handled correctly.

Have tried reinstalling CT 2.5 but no joy...

B.

Comment: Seems the CT gateway has adjusted the amounts when using the discount code, but these are not been picked up correctly by PayPal when its been passed over...

Comment: Narrowed this down to having something to do with shipping.. as soon as i deactivate the shipping it works again..

Comment: Okay if i add a code in that basically removes the price so all your pay for is the postage/shipping then the error appears.. if i then create the code and leave even 1p of the actual item to pay as well as the postage it works fine. It also works fine with NO shipping.. has to be a bug in here somewhere CartThrob guys?

Comment: Noticed that you can be sent to different versions of the PayPal express screen too... quite randomly!